# Meteor Microscope Activate Cursor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

Within the Discover Meteor Book project called Microscope.  How do you enable the cursor when a user clicks on the "Submit Post" or the "Discuss" button?  Currently, after a user clicks on the "Submit Post" or "Discuss" button, the user has to use a mouse to click in the field to move the cursor there in order to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use templates `onRendered` lifecycle event along with standard jQuery objects `focus` method.

Suppose your template is named `postSubmit`, then add this code to make the first input (or textarea, or whatever...) grab focus.

```
Template.postSubmit.onRendered(function(){
  this.$("input:first, textarea:first, select:first").focus();
});
```

Comment: I got it working on the post_Submit.js but not on the comment_Submit.js ?? @saimeunt

Comment: That's because the comment submit form contains a textarea, not an input (see my edit).

Comment: @jmar42 Ok, no problem! Accepting an answer adds points to his reputation. And as you go around the site and see answers you find useful, upvoting them does the same, and also means that the best answers bubble up to the top.